# node.js or PHP for image processing

Tags: php, node.js, image-processing

We are working on an image-processing application. It involves applying filters, Gaussian etc. We want to make it a highly concurrent application.
This will be on multiple single core ec2 instances.

Since Imageprocessing is an cpu intensive operation, we are thinking node.js gets blocked in event loop, so thinking to use php. We are not able to find any benchmarks in this area. Any inputs on this will be a great help.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing much more about whether you need to push a large number of images through, or a small number of large images, or a tiny number of images which each need massive processing, or anything about the processing involved. Is speed really the main criterion? Or is it speed per unit cost as far as possible on a single CPU machine? Your algorithm could make more difference than the language. And if you really want speed, you should consider C/C++.

Comment: I need to prcoess large number of small images. The processing is to convert image to pencil sketch(invert+guassianfilter and dodging). I hope applying Guassian takes good amount of processing. Speed is the main criterion

Comment: Tribute to the great, one and only Carl Friedrich Gauss

Answer (score 1):

Its a CPU-bound task. Really well optimized PHP or Node will probably perform similarly. I/O concurrency will not affect CPU bound tasks on single core.  On many core the I/O may come into play, but realistically most platforms including PHP have efficient strategies for concurrent I/O now.  Also you are likely to end up calling out to C or C++ code regardless.

If you really want (cost-effective) performance, drop the single core thing, put some large basically gaming or bitcoin mining PCs in the office, find a nice way to distribute the tasks among the machine(s) and a way to process multiple images concurrently on the GPUs.  None of that is in actuality tied to a particular programming language.

Comment: wont nodejs eventloop gets blocked since it is single threaded.

Comment: Yes, but if there are multiple PHP processes or threads they will also be blocked on one CPU.  Technically Node has webworker-threads which operate concurrently although they must copy all data in and out.  But normal Node clusters can process concurrently fine.  With one core none of that matters.

Comment: It will come down to the details of your implementation.  Depending on how exactly you do it, which version or type of PHP/Node/OS/etc., either could be faster.  If you insist on one core period then you have no clue.  You can get by with multiple VMs or containers if they each get their own virtual core.  As I said to truly maximize performance use GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not highly concurrent and each request will block until it's done. Node would be fine as long as it's mainly doing I/O, or waiting for another process to return, e.g. calling `convert` (ImageMagick), rather than doing any processing itself. The more CPU cores you have to run the actual conversion on, the better.

Answer (score 0):

For image processing, I recommend to use PHP instead of Node.js because there are many great PHP packages that can help you work with images easily. Don't worry about the performance of PHP7 or HHVM :)